# cascading dropdown list on mvc4 not updating nor loading javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I'm currently trying to create a new set of cascading dropdown lists by following this tutorial :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

problem is it doesnt work and I'm basically illiterate on javascript (currently I dont have the time to sit and learn it), somehow the dropdown lists are not working, only the first one shows the first hierarchy info.

This is what I've done:

First the controller:

Here's the index method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = repo.GetParentEstablishments();

         ViewBag.Parent = (new SelectList(list.ToArray(),"EstablishmentId","Name"));
        return View();

    }
```

Here's the method that's supposed to return the list of children for the selected father:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Children(int parentId)
    {
        var parents = repo.GetChildrenEstablishments(parentId);
        return Json(new SelectList(parents, "EstablishmentId", "Name"));
    }
```

Here's the view for the index method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post, new { id =     "ParentChildrenFormID", data_childrenListAction = @Url.Action("ChildrenList") }))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend> Parent/Children</legend>
    @Html.DropDownList("Parents", ViewBag.Parent as SelectList, "Select a Parent", new {id="ParentsID"})
    <div id="ChildrenDivId">
        <label for="Children">Children </label>
        <select id="ChildrenID" name="Children"></select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type ="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}
<script src ="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/parentChildren.js")"></script>
```

And finally here's the script file:

```
$(function () {

$('#ChildrenDivId').hide();
$('#SubmitID').hide();

$('#ParentsID').change(function () {
    var URL = $('#ParentChildrenFormID').data('childrenListAction');
    $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#ParentsID').val(), function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select a Children</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, child) {
            items += "<option value='" + child.value+ "'>" + child.Name + "</option>";
            // state.Value cannot contain ' character. We are OK because state.Value = cnt++;
        });
        $('#ChildrenID').html(items);
        $('#StatesDivID').show();

    });
});

$('#ChildrenID').change(function () {
    $('#SubmitID').show();
});
});
```

For what I've managed to understand from the javascript function, the div that has the label and dropdown for the children should appear hidden once the page is loaded and appear once the user selects a parent from the first list, currently this is not happening and instead everything shows up once the page is loaded. Also once I select a parent nothing happens on the second list, **I can infer from this that the javascrip file is not being executed on the users browser, why isn't it being executed? what am I doing wrong?**

Thank in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on the following line

```
items += "<option value='" + child.value + "'>" + child.Name + "</option>";
```

Which should be:

```
items += "<option value='" + child.Value + "'>" + child.Text + "</option>";
```

Since your controller action is returning a `SelectList`, this class is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` where `SelectListItem` has 2 properties called `Value` and `Text`.

There's also another issue with your code. You have used the folllowing to construct the url to your controller action:

```
URL + '/' + $('#ParentsID').val()
```

which will result in an url of the form:

```
/SomeController/Children/123
```

But the action argument of your `Children` action is called `parentId`. If you are using the default route setup, only an `{id}` parameter will be sent as part og of the uri path (that's the default route pattern: `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and not `{controller}/{action}/{parentid}`). So you should either change your route setup or pass the parentId parameter like this:

```
$.getJSON(URL, { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) {
    ...
});
```

Yet another issue with your code is that your Children conrtoller action is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute but the `$.getJSON` method sends a GET request. So it won't work. You could use the `$.post` method instead:

```
$.post(URL, { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) {
    ...
});
```

Another issue is that you are showing the `StatesDivID` but your actual div that was hidden is `ChildrenDivId`. Make sure you are showing the proper element:

```
$('#ChildrenDivId').show();
```

Also make sure you have the jQuery script referenced before your `parentChildren.js` script. Right now you have included your script inside the view but cannot see jQuery being included. Maybe you have it in your _Layout.

I would recommend you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome developer toolbar to analyze your javascript code.

Comment: Ok so apparently my issues are located on the javascript file, I added the JQuery reference on my view and now it hides the secondary list and the submit button, problem is now its not showing the second list as soon as a click an item on the first, could it be that I'm referencing the wrong method on my controller? problem is I  don't know where it is referenced I mean, how do I know which method am I calling back from my js file on my controller? The method that returns the children

Comment: from a parent is called Children and receives an int called parentId, now I havent created a view for this method because from what I've understood the whole deal with this is to do it on the client side and not have to reload a page, am I right?

Comment: You are sending an AJAX request to your Children controller action. The url is calculated on the server and stored in the `data-childrenListAction` attribute on your form. Its value is generated on the server with `@Url.Action("ChildrenList")`. You don't need to create any view for the Children action because you are returning JSON from it. This JSON is then consumed on the client and a select list is dynamically built with javascript.

Comment: I've debugged it with firebug and so far it does not enter the ParentsID change function when I click on it nor does it enter the Children function on my controller, sigh I just dont get it, what could it be?

Comment: Did you change the `$.getJSON` call as shown in my answer: `$.getJSON(URL, { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) { ... });`? Also try hardcoding the value of the controller action first: `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Children")', { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) { ... });`.

Comment: Yes I did, heres the new line $.getJSON(URL, { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) {

Comment: Look at the `Net` tab in FireBug. Normally you should see whether an AJAX request is being sent to the server. Also look at the `Console` tab where potential javascript errros could be displayed.

Comment: Yes, it's this one:http://localhost:10814/ticket/index?parentId=1    Doesn't it mean i need to implement the [HttpPost] of my index method?

Comment: This is sending a request to the `Index` action and not the `Children` action. Try like this: `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Children")', { parentId: $('#ParentsID').val() }, function (data) { ... });`. You could indeed decorate the `Children` action with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Why could that be? thats what i don't understand, where is it referenced what method I'm calling back as soon as the users click an item?

Comment: The URL variable is constructed like this: `var URL = $('#ParentChildrenFormID').data('childrenListAction');`. So as I said in my previous comment this is reading the value of the `data-childrenListAction` attribute on the `<form>`. But apparently this is not working as expected. What's the value of the `URL` variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27242/discussion-between-oskar132-and-darin-dimitrov)